# Android, Calculate taps per second?

Tags: android, time, tap

The title is pretty much self explanatory, i want when the user taps rapidly on the screen to accurately as possible count the current 'taps per second' any ideas?

thanks

Comment: I was more so hoping for a method to counting the taps, without using some sort of counter, i've tried researching for some info on this but seem to not be able to find ANYONE else talking about it

Comment: Why don't you want to use a counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I think its possible to do:

1. Set a Timer
2. Invoke View's onTouch (to do this, you may need to create a custom view), self increase 1 for each touch
3. Do calculation

Comment: Certainly good enough for me, though wouldnt this only be able to show the taps per second when the user has 'finished' the game, rather than a live count

Comment: @xBroak the `onTouch` event is fired at real time (it will get fired at the same time user touches the screen), so literally it can show the live count.